# if $m \lt n$, then $mk < nk$.

Tags: induction, natural-numbers

How can I prove the following for n,m and k natural numbers (k isn't equal to 0)

if $m \lt n$, then $mk < nk$.

Comments: I'll use induction for k.
I have already proven with induction that: if $m \lt n$, then $m+k \lt n+k$

Comment: Why do you think we need induction? Because $$mk-nk=k(m-n)<0$$

Comment: @user1094359 if $m<n$ then $m-n$ is not a natural number so that may not be allowed in this context.  If you can use properties of real numbers then the question may be close to the axiom "if $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, then $xy \ge 0$"

Comment: @Henry I think we can still write an equivalent statement $n>m$ and...$k(n-m)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $m<n \Rightarrow m+c<n+c$.

Base case $k=1$:

$m1 = m < n = n1$

Inductive hypothesis: Suppose $m\ell < n\ell$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $m\ell + m < n\ell + m < n\ell + n$

$\Rightarrow m(\ell + 1) < n(\ell + 1)$.

By induction our statement is proven.